# Remove invalid characters from string using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I found several posts on this topic but solution mentioned there doesn't work in my case.

Consider following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rgs = "^[ -~]*(?:\r?\n[ -~]*)*$";

        string TestStrNoMatch = "One\tTwo\r\nThree Ö";
        string TestStrMatch = "OneTwo\r\nThree ";

        Regex rgx = new Regex(rgs);

        bool Match = rgx.IsMatch(TestStrNoMatch); // false

        Match = rgx.IsMatch(TestStrMatch); // true

        string result = Regex.Replace(TestStrNoMatch, rgs, "");

        // result is the same as TestStrNoMatch
    }
```

Expected result is for \t and Ö to be removed but this is not happening. Value of result is exactly the same as TestStrNoMatch

**CLARIFICATION**: The regex I use in my example only allows characters between space and ~ (English letters, numbers and some special characters) and new line in Windows and Unix format. I want to remove everything else.

Comment: If the regex doesn’t match, it can’t obviously match in the replace either

Comment: What exactly is your goal? What kind of characters exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(TestStrNoMatch, rgs, "");` - since `TestStrNoMatch` **has no matches** for `rgs` pattern then `Regex.Replace` does **nothing** - there no matches to remove (replace with `""`)

Comment: @NickDechiara: the goal is for \t and Ö to be removed. It is mentioned at the bottom of my post.

Comment: If those are the only things you'd like to remove, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex needs to match the characters you want to remove in order for regex.replace to work. Because your pattern doesn't match anything, nothing gets replaced. It's unclear what specifically you want to remove, but here's an example:

The pattern `(\\t)|(Ö)` matches the tab and Ö characters, so

```
    string sample = "ab\tcefÖ";
    string pattern = "(\\t)|(Ö)";
    string result = Regex.Replace(sample, pattern, "");
    System.Console.WriteLine("SAMPLE : " + sample);
    System.Console.WriteLine("RESULT : " + result);
```

Results in

```
SAMPLE: ab      cefÖ
RESULT: abcef
```

If you explain what all you want to remove exactly, I can point you towards a more representative regex pattern. E.g., to remove all characters between space and ~, as well as tabs, you could use `[^ -~]|(\\t)`.

Comment: This pattern: [^ -~]|(\\t) will remove all characters that are not between space and ~, and will also remove tabs

Comment: The regex I use in my example only allows characters between space and ~ (English letters, numbers and some special characters) and new line in Windows and Unix format. I want to remove everything else. [EDIT: added that I want to allow new line as well]

Comment: @JoeSchmoe the pattern I posted in that comment / my edited answer will allow new line and meet the rest of your specifications.

Comment: this seems to be the answer (I am still testing): "[^ -~|\\r|\\n]"

Comment: Yes, that pattern appears to work as well, from my testing

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this instead of using Regex? Better readability in my opinion.

```
string text = "abcdef";
char[] invalidChars = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; // Your invalid characters here

if (text.IndexOfAny(invalidChars) != -1)
{
    text = new String(text.Where(c => !invalidChars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
}
```

output: "def"

Comment: It's mostly a matter of preference, but regex can be easier if you have a range of characters or special considerations (e.g. Regex.Replace(text,"[a-z]","") is a lot easier than writing out invalidChars = { 'a', 'b', ..., 'z'}, I think)

Comment: but what if you want to exclude all of the unicode chars? do you want to type them all out? good luck

Comment: @sLw is correct. I am trying to white-list certain set of characters and remove everything else. I updated OP to reflect that.

Comment: You could certainly do the reverse and use `validchars` in that case. This was what I used to filter out windows paths invalid characters so I agree it depends on use case and isn't very feasible with large character sets.